# How do I call an external program from Flash Professional CS6?

Tags: flash

I am trying to do some automation in Flash and need to call an external program but I can't figure it out.  I've found many references to fl.system.fscommand but that doesn't appear to be available to me.

I'm not trying to call this from the actionscript IN the flash document, but from a script called via "Commands -> Run Command...".  Maybe I'm just searching for the wrong terms but all I can find is calling programs from within flash itself with fscommand.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots more searching, I eventually found the answer:

`FLfile.runCommandLine()`

I found it via a defunct middleware script.  Hopefully this helps anyone else who is trying to figure out how to automate Flash Professional.